# Django model with number of fields less than corresponding database table

Tags: python, mysql, django

If a database table contains 100 fields, and a django application utilises only a few fields say 1 or 2, does the corresponding django model needs to be declared with 100 fields?

Comment: Can you reword your question, it's not really clear and what do you hope to achieve

Comment: Do you mean that you already have table in DB and you want to create django model for that table?

Comment: I already have table which was created by some other application and I need to utilize some of the fields from this table to do some computation. The problem is the table is composed of 180 fields and I require only 3 fields out of the whole set for all my computations.

Comment: so what's the problem then? Are those fields already having some values in them? if not why not just create another table with those 3 fields ?

Comment: Creating an additional table would require modifying the original application which created the table with 180 columns so that the corresponding fields are updated in new table also. The other option would be to schedule syncing of tables regularly.

Comment: You can also create a view with the 3 fields, and point a full-fledged Django model against the view (you'll need to verify that e.g. `save()` still works for your database..

Answer (score 2):

No, you do not need to declare the Django model with all the fields from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Django comes with a utility called inspectdb that can create models by introspecting an existing database

`python manage.py inspectdb`

Save this as a file by using standard Unix output redirection:

`python manage.py inspectdb > models.py`

This will reduce the stress of manually defining the model.

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/legacy-databases/